# Remove WooCommerce Process Login action

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin to check if email/username is verified.

I need to override or replace process_login action in woocommerce's `includes/class-wc-form-handler.php` file through my plugin.

I have created custom function for login. but before that I want to remove `process_login` function.

I tried this code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_default_login_process' );
function remove_default_login_process(){
    if ( class_exists('WC_Form_Handler') ) {    
     remove_action('wp_loaded',array('WC_Form_Handler','process_login',20));
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded','my_custom_login_process',20);

function my_custom_login_process(){
    //Code for Login and verify email
}
```

But nothing worked till now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your custom action with higher priority to override the WC_Form_Handler

```
add_action('wp_loaded','my_custom_login_process',10);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor change in **remove_action** function to make it work. The first closing bracket after **the priority / 20** should come before **20**.

```
remove_action('wp_loaded', array(WC_Form_Handler,'process_login'), 20);
```